# IOS: Facebook login crash on iOS. again

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Some time ago I updated the SDK in my iOS project. Testers of my application began to send me reports about a bug, when they tried login - they have immediately crash. Its happens on iPad 3 (iOS 8.1.2). In all others devices and iOS versions - all ok.

This is source there crash:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init]; //ok, not null
[login logInWithReadPermissions:permissions_list
        fromViewController:gMainView.rootViewController
        handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) 
        {
                      //....
        }
```

and when I call login crash  happens. Log file contain this string:

```
... <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: logging_token)'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x248dc5f7 0x3242ac77 0x247f97e5 0x529737 0x529b11 0x529aa5 0x528791 0x4e82c7 0x33b60f 0xf5747 0x20a54d 0x2636df 0x3c2687 0x3c23b9 0x3c24f3 0x4107bd 0x20a47b 0x174775 0x1744b9 0x391023 0x3911a9 0x4de663 0x257417dd 0x257428db 0x277faaeb 0x277fa953 0x2c0b182f 0x258061ed 0x248923a5 0x248a27f3 0x248a278f 0x248a0db1 0x247edb31 0x247ed943 0x2bba4051 0x27de36f1 0x365e21 0x329c6aaf)
```

There is a special solution for ipad and iOS 8.1.2?

And another question: in documentation doesn't specify the minimal version as iOS 8.0, but when I build project, xcode throw worning about facebook libraries minimal version as 8.0. As result, my project can't start on devices witch iOS 7. Do I something wrong?

Thanks for yours the answers and advices :)

PS: I use xcode 8.3.3, ios facebook sdk 4.24

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?